# Deploy Vaadin23 Application with Docker

Tags: docker, vaadin

There is a blog, how to do it with Java Version 11:
https://vaadin.com/blog/how-to-create-a-docker-container-for-a-vaadin-java-app
When i follow this guide and use Java11 for the Application, everything is good.
But when i try to use the same manner for Java17 (the latest LTS), the docker image build is successfull, but the container crashes with a tomcat-server issue:
[error log at running container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykFHg.png)

Did anyone ran the same issue or know how to fix this. The blog-post about dockerize a vaadin app seems to be outdated, and there isn't one out for Java version 17.

To replicate the issue, go to the starter https://start.vaadin.com/app and choose Java 17. Then follow this Blogpost https://vaadin.com/blog/how-to-create-a-docker-container-for-a-vaadin-java-app to dockerize it and replace the openjdk-image version to 17.
Build and then run the container. Appreciate any help.

Comment: The instructions in the blogpost fail with Java 17 because the `Dockerfile` is using Java 11 image (at the line: `FROM openjdk:11`). As Mikael Sukoinen, you can download an update to date `Dockerfile` from start.vaadin.com, or alternatively check the docs for instructions on how to build a `Dockerfile`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also the actual error is most likely before the error you pasted.

Comment: Okay sorry, i will keep that in mind for the future. Thanks for that hint.

Answer (score 2):

You can check a box for "Docker config" under Java version in [start.vaadin.com](https://start.vaadin.com) to generate a Dockerfile for your app before downloading.

[image: docker configuration location in vaadin start]

You can then build the container using the `docker build . -t myapp:latest` command and run it on localhost using `docker run -p 8080:8080 myapp:latest`

You can also find these instructions and instructions on how to add a Dockerfile to existing Vaadin 23 applications in the Vaadin 23 technical documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/production/docker